# Why is my Named Based Virtualhost not working?

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf, vhosts

My virtual host configuration looks like this:

```
Listen 80
...
DocumentRoot "/www/mysite"
...
<Directory "/www/mysite">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
...
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
...
NameVirtualHost *:80
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName theag.com
    ServerAlias www.theag.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/mysite"
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Although the localhost works, when I try to connect to the ServerName ***theag.com*** as described in the VirtualHost section, I get a ***Server not found***.
What am i doing wrong? or What am I supposed to do to get it it working?

p.s. `...` signifies the configuration lines in between.

> Workaround : For testing purposes this is what I have done:

I just edited the /etc/hosts, 
from 
`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4`
to 
`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 theag.com 
www.theag.com`. 

This will get it to work. You will be using the 127.0.0.1 as the ip-address for now.

Comment: Assuming you didn't obfuscate your domain names - there is no address record for `www.theag.com` in your public DNS zone.

Comment: I just edited the /etc/hosts, from `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4` to `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 theag.com www.theag.com`. I supppose it should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to arrange the domain's DNS to point to your server's IP address. If `theag.com` is the actual name, it's currently not associated with any IP address (neither is `www.theag.com`). Talk to the folks who manage your nameservers.

Comment: I though that is the issue here. Can i set up local resolution for the domain theag.com?

Comment: I just edited the /etc/hosts, from `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4` to `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 theag.com www.theag.com`. I supppose it should work now.